# How to search multiple values in a column with contains?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a list with searchitems:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #searchitems

SELECT 'Road' as  item
INTO #searchitems
UNION 
SELECT 'Bike'
```

| item |
| --- |
| Road |
| Bike |

And I want looking for rows that contain that items

I put a Full Text Index on the Name column and I tried this already

```
SELECT Name
FROM [AdventureWorksLT2019].[SalesLT].[Product]
WHERE CONTAINS(*, (Select item FROM #searchitems) )
```

But it does not work. With just one value its working but not with a list of search values.
Does it even possible with CONTAINS on a SQL-Server.

I expect something like this:

```
SELECT distinct Name
FROM [AdventureWorksLT2019].[SalesLT].[Product]
WHERE CONTAINS(*, 'Road OR Bike' )
```

[expected output, but why its not working on a input list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gH4sJ.png)

Comment: Please show both sample input data and expected result as tables with text here in your question, do not provide images or links.

Comment: can only post image as links. Not enough reputation

Comment: What should "not enough reputation" mean? Here you can read how to create tables in your question, this has nothing to do with reputation: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277716/how-can-i-create-a-table-in-a-post. Are you after LIKE? SELECT name
FROM yourtable
WHERE 
name LIKE '%Road%' OR 
name LIKE '%Bike%';

Comment: *can only post image as links.* do not post [pictures](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551) of data *at all!* - [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @JonasMetzler Jetzt somethink like the LIKE with %, but how do it with a list of searchitems.

Answer (score 0):

Refere the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sql/t-sql/queries/contains-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

```
SELECT distinct Name
FROM [AdventureWorksLT2019].[SalesLT].[Product]
WHERE CONTAINS(*, 'Road OR Bike' )
```

Is working, official example:

```
SELECT Name  
FROM Production.Product  
WHERE CONTAINS(Name, ' Mountain OR Road ')
```

**Update**

maybe that's your solution :

```
SELECT Name
FROM [AdventureWorksLT2019].[SalesLT].[Product]
WHERE CONTAINS(*, (Select STRING_AGG(item, ' OR ') FROM #searchitems)
```

Comment: update does not work

Comment: @Petersselorse - I can't be bothered to set up a test table with full text indexing but maybe assigning the string agg result to a variable and then using `WHERE CONTAINS(*, @string_agg_result)` would work. Example H indicates a variable should be accepted there https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sql/t-sql/queries/contains-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#h-using-contains-with-variables

Comment: Yes this is also what I thougt. Great idea. What I notice I can not use containe with spaced text. Is that right. SELECT Name
FROM [AdventureWorksLT2019].[SalesLT].[Product]
WHERE CONTAINS(name,  'Cable Lock')

Comment: @Petersselorse - I haven't worked with FTS for years but `WHERE CONTAINS(name, '"Cable Lock"')`? for phrasres?

Comment: The String_AGG OR is great, but if that string is to long then you get a error.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use a `CTE` and `JOIN` it to your table with `LIKE`:

```
WITH searchitems AS
(SELECT 'Road' AS item
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Bike')
SELECT DISTINCT y.name
FROM yourtable y
JOIN searchitems s
ON y.name LIKE CONCAT('%',s.item,'%');
```

In the `CTE`, you can select as many items as desired.

You should generally note that lots of `LIKE` conditions can slow down your query if your table holds very many entries (and of course, similar ideas like `CONTAINS` can be very slow, too).

This should be avoided if possible and be replaced with an exact string search to improve the execution time.

Then of course the way shown above is no more required, you could just use a standard `IN` clause:

```
SELECT name
FROM yourtable
WHERE 
name IN ('Road','Bike','Hello World','Another Text');
```

Try out with some sample data: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/reZHN4br)

Comment: This seems a bit disingenuous to avoid the question (which was about `CONTAINS` ) and give an answer about `LIKE` and then try and lump `LIKE` and `CONTAINS` together in the same performance bucket. The whole point of CONTAINS is that it uses a full text index

Comment: Well, the question, as I understand it, is mainly about how to check the table for a given list of names or of items. It doesn't tell us this has urgently to be done using CONTAINS. In my opinion, it wouldn't make sense to just exclude any other options to filter the data. CONTAINS is no panacea or only solution for such things. Lots of analysis have shown the performance of such queries will much more depend on table size and indexes used rather than using LIKE or CONTAINS.